# Using LINQ to group social networking links for each user

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a model named `User`. Each user can have some social links. Now I want to get all users with their social link as a single row in the result. Here are my models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SocialLink> SocialLinks { get; set; }
}

public class SocialLink
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public SocialType Type { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public enum SocialType
{
    FaceBook    = 0,
    Twitter     = 1,
    Youtube     = 2,
    Linkedin    = 3,
    GooglePlus  = 4,
    Telegram    = 5,
    Instagram   = 6
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Youtube { get; set; }
    public string Linkedin { get; set; }
    public string GooglePlus { get; set; }
    public string Telegram { get; set; }
    public string Instagram { get; set; }
}
```

I want my query to be like this in the result:

```
Name    | Facebook | Twitter  | Youtube | Linkedin | GooglePlus | Telegram | Instagram
======================================================================================
Someone | facebook | @someone | youtube | linkedin | google     | @tele    | @someins
```

I have written following query, It works as I expected but I wonder if there's a better way for doing this:

```
users.Select(p => new UserViewModel {
            Name = p.Name,
            Facebook = p.SocialLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == SocialType.FaceBook).Url ?? "#",
            Twitter = p.SocialLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == SocialType.Twitter).Url ?? "#",
            Youtube = p.SocialLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == SocialType.Youtube).Url ?? "#",
            Linkedin = p.SocialLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == SocialType.Linkedin).Url ?? "#",
            Telegram = p.SocialLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == SocialType.Telegram).Url ?? "#",
            Instagram = p.SocialLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == SocialType.Instagram).Url ?? "#",
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I would create a constructor for `UserViewModel` that accepts Name and a collection of `SocialLink`. Inside constructor I would use `foreach ` to populate properties. In your case, every call `FirstOrDefault` creates an `IEnumerator` that may slow down your app if there are many users.

Comment: @YuriTceretian Comments are for seeking clarification. Please post suggestions as answers, not as comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary` and make properties of `UserViewModel` to address elements of this dictionary as follows:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    private readonly Dictionary<SocialType, string> SocialLinks;

    public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
        SocialLinks = (user.SocialLinks ?? new SocialLink[0])
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Url);
        Name = user.Name;
    }

    private string GetUrl(SocialType socialType)
    {
        string url;
        return SocialLinks.TryGetValue(socialType, out url) && url != null ? url : "#";
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Facebook
    {
        get { return GetUrl(SocialType.FaceBook); }
        set { SocialLinks[SocialType.FaceBook] = value; }
    }
    public string Twitter
    {
        get { return GetUrl(SocialType.Twitter); }
        set { SocialLinks[SocialType.Twitter] = value; }
    }
    public string Youtube
    {
        get { return GetUrl(SocialType.Youtube); }
        set { SocialLinks[SocialType.Youtube] = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then your query will looks like:

```
users.Select(u => new UserViewModel(u)).ToList();
```

Comment: Great, By the way Name belongs to User not Social Links:
`users.Select(u => new UserViewModel(u.SocialLinks, u.Name)).ToList();`

Comment: Even prettier as `(socialLinks ?? Enumerable.Empty<SocialLink>).ToDictionary(..)`

Comment: I also think using `SingleOrDefault` would better show that there is always either one link or none if this is not the case then the dictionary will crash trying to insert duplicate keys.

Comment: Why not pass User and get the Name from that

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the current solution is not effective because every time you call `FirstOrDefault` method it creates enumerator and enumerates until element meets predicate. The `SocialLink` collection is not expected to be big (0-20 elements) but the collection is users may be big. And creation such a model for 100 users may create some overhead as well as pressure to GC.

The solution with dictionary is more effective than `FirstOrDefault`, however you have to still deal with possible duplicates and population of dictionary is relatively expensive operation.

I would propose another solution, that seems a little more effective than dictionary, but not so elegant.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public UserViewModel(String name, IEnumerable<SocialLink> links)
   {
      this.Name = name;
      if (links != null){
         foreach(var link in links)
         {
            switch (link.SocialType)
            {
                case SocialType.FaceBook:
                    FaceBook = link.Url;
                    break;
                case SocialType.Twitter:
                    Twitter = link.Url;
                    break;
                case SocialType.Youtube:
                    Youtube = link.Url;
                    break;
                case SocialType.Linkedin:
                    Linkedin = link.Url;
                    break;
                case SocialType.GooglePlus:
                    GooglePlus = link.Url;
                    break;
                case SocialType.Telegram:
                    Telegram = link.Url;
                    break;
                case SocialType.Instagram:
                    Instagram = link.Url;
                    break;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Facebook { get; set; }
   public string Twitter { get; set; }
   public string Youtube { get; set; }
   public string Linkedin { get; set; }
   public string GooglePlus { get; set; }
   public string Telegram { get; set; }
   public string Instagram { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you create enumerator object and scan collection only once. You can improve to not assign property if it has already a value.

PS. I would change your enum to start from 1, and leave 0 for exceptional cases, because `0` is a default value you may end up with some awkward bugs.

Comment: Appart from the fact that you have a hard-coded `switch` you've just created a new solution _last-or-default_ :-]

Comment: In this case no, because I create enumerator only once. Logically it is `LastOrDefault`.

Comment: _population of dictionary is relatively expensive operation_ - this needs a proof.

Comment: I do not see any problems with hard-coded switch in this particular case. Do you?

Comment: @t3chb0t, I would suggest you to look at source code of method Dictionary<T,TR>.Add. It is way more complex than property assignment .

Comment: `switch` is already hard to maintain, you should aviod them like hell. I'd never use a switch here if everything could be done dynamically. You add one more value and need to adjust a dozen of files.

Comment: Complex code does not mean it's inefficient... besides in most cases like this one, this is not ever measurelable.

Comment: @t3chb0t, why? You already hardcoded properties :) Adding switch do not introduce more "hard-code" because once you need to add new SocialType, you will have to add new property.

Comment: @t3chb0t So a hard-coded switch that eliminates a hard-coded LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use hard-coded social links as properties on the `UserViewModel` but instead simplify it to

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SocialLink> SocialLinks { get; set; }
}
```

and let the view render a dynamic list of links and format the Url properly for display. The code-behind should not do it.

With this simplification the query becomes

```
var result = users.Select(p => new UserViewModel
{
    Name = p.Name,
    SocialLinks = 
        p.SocialLinks
        .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
        .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
        .ToList()   
}).ToList();
```

Nothing is hard-coded anymore. The only thing you need to ever adjust in case of more social link types is probably the view but even this should render just fine without any additional maintenance.

Comment: I wanted to moan about hardcoding all the types but couldn't be bothered, so glad to see you did ;). I would go further and get rid of the enum, and subclass each social type - surely there are methods you'd want to call on each social link, whose return value should depend on the type. That would get rid of more switch statements down the line.

Comment: @eurotrash definitely an idea worth considering but in this small example I doubt there is much we can do more.

Comment: But the view will likely access the specific property in several places so it would make for more work.

Comment: @Paparazzi yes, and display it dynamically as a list because it is one and should be treated as one

Comment: @t3chb0t OP already had a List.  To me he is clearly asking for individual properties also.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public class SocialLink
> {
>     public string Url { get; set; }
>     public SocialType Type { get; set; }
>     public User User { get; set; }
>     public int UserId { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Why repeat User, and UserId?
Why repeat UserId if User has an Id?

I don't like this

```
public string Facebook { get; set; }
```

People are to have and expectation they can revise SocialLinks and it does not.

I would do the work in UserViewModel and derive from User
If you have other selects you would need to repeats the code

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
//pop users
List<UserViewModel> usersVM = users.Select(p => new UserViewModel(p)).ToList();

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SocialLink> SocialLinks { get; set; }
    public User(int id, string name, ICollection<SocialLink> socialLinks)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        SocialLinks = socialLinks;
    }
    public User(User user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        Name = user.Name;
        SocialLinks = user.SocialLinks;
    }
}
public class SocialLink
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public SocialType Type { get; set; }
    public SocialLink(string url, SocialType type)
    {
        Url = url;
        Type = type;
    }
}
public class UserViewModel : User
{
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Youtube { get; set; }
    public string Linkedin { get; set; }
    public string GooglePlus { get; set; }
    public string Telegram { get; set; }
    public string Instagram { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel (User user) : base(user)
    {
        PopLinks();
    }
    public UserViewModel(int id, string name, ICollection<SocialLink> socialLinks) : base(id, name, socialLinks)
    {
        PopLinks();
    }
    public void PopLinks()
    {
        if (SocialLinks != null)
        {
            foreach (var link in SocialLinks)
            {   // borrowed from another answer +1
                switch (link.Type)
                {
                    case SocialType.FaceBook:
                        Facebook = link.Url;
                        break;
                    case SocialType.Twitter:
                        Twitter = link.Url;
                        break;
                    case SocialType.Youtube:
                        Youtube = link.Url;
                        break;
                    case SocialType.Linkedin:
                        Linkedin = link.Url;
                        break;
                    case SocialType.GooglePlus:
                        GooglePlus = link.Url;
                        break;
                    case SocialType.Telegram:
                        Telegram = link.Url;
                        break;
                    case SocialType.Instagram:
                        Instagram = link.Url;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My read is that `User` might be a navigation property.

Comment: @t3chb0t Yes it is a navigation property.